# K&R excercise 1-21 Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing

Tags: beginner, c

> Exercise 1-21. Write a program entab that replaces strings of blanks
> by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing.
> Use the same tab stops as for detab. When either a tab or a single
> blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given
> preference?

The code I wrote :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define TAB 8 /* number of characters between two tab stops */

int main()
{
    int i, r, c;

    i = 0; /* number of space characters replaceable by a tab character */
    r = 0; /* number of unreplaceable characters since the last tab stop */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            if (r + (++i) == TAB)
            {
                i > 1 ? putchar('\t') : putchar(' ');
                r = i = 0;
            }
        }

        else if (isspace(c))
        {
            while (i--)
                putchar(' ');
            
            putchar(c);
            r = i = 0;
        }

        else
        {
            for (r += i+1; i; i--) /* encountered a nonblank character, spaces are now unreplaceable */
                putchar(' ');
            
            putchar(c);

            r %= TAB;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What compiler, what C standard?

Answer (score 5):

**Review goals**

Best to state them. I'll assume a general review.

**What characters are *blank* and *tab*?**

C has standard (the "C" locale) *whitespaces* including: space (`' '`), form feed (`'\f'`), new-line (`'\n'`), carriage return (`'\r'`), horizontal tab (`'\t'`), and vertical tab (`'\v'`).

Code treats space (`' '`) as *blanks*, which is reasonable.
C has a `isblank()` which is true for space (`' '`), and horizontal tab (`'\t'`), which is not suitable for this task.  Good that it is not used.

Code treats the non-space *whitespaces* as *tab* and so `r` and `i` are set to 0.  This is reasonable in the "C" locale.  Yet `else if (isspace(c))` deserves a comment expressing this since `isspace()` does not look like a *tab* test.

**Advanced**: Outside the "C" locale, other white spaces could be better treated as a *space* such as [non-breaking space](https://www.ascii-code.com/CP1252/160)

**Trailing blanks bug?**

With input like `"ab   "` (note no trailing `'\n'`), code outputs `"ab"`, which is reasonable yet by strict reading of the requirements I'd say `"ab   "` is expected.

**Consider initialization at declaration time**

```
//int i, r, c;
//i = 0;
//r = 0;

int i = 0;
int r = 0;
int c;
```

**Good type choice**

`c` is correctly an `int` and not a `char` to handle the 257 values from `getchar()` and `is...()` usage..

**Variable names are quite terse**

Instead of `c`, perhaps `ch`?
Instead of `i`, perhaps `space_count`?
Instead of `r`, perhaps TBD?

**Re-word comment?**

`r = 0; /* number of unreplaceable characters since the last tab stop */` deserves re-wording.  It is not only the last *tab stop*, but any non-*space* *whitespace*.  I do not have a good alternative.

**Implementation choice not explicit**

Requirements have "When either a tab or a single blank would suffice to reach a tab stop, which should be given preference?", yet it take code analysis to determine what was done.  An explicit comment is deserved.

Perhaps steer code via a macro to allow either approach.

**Minor: Unpack side effects**

`if (r + (++i) == TAB)` is OK.

I find the below more clear.

```
i++;
if (r + i == TAB)
```

**Minor: style issues**

Why the blank line between lines of code?

```
            putchar(c);

            r %= TAB;
```

Comment: Kind of the opposite, but it's irrelevant in context so I deleted the comment